# Did I really flag this question twice?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, flagging

[I edited this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1515032/fourth-order-derivative-of-the-lagrange-polynomial) and found that it is unclear.
I flagged it as such.

I tried to [be nice](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) and leave a comment explaining how we roll on math.SE (and SE in general).
As the asker only had one rep, I checked his profile to see if this is his first time around and if it makes sense to include a welcome message in the comment.

I found that the question that I edited was pretty much a copy of a [previously asked, closed one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1508564/fourth-order-derivative-of-lagrange-polynomial)

I went back to flag it as a duplicate, but to my surprise I apparently already did that:

[image]

I'm not aware of flagging this question twice.

I checked my profile to see my flags, which suggests the opposite, only showing this one flag:
[image]

Does the flag-summary on the profile only show one flag per question?
Or is this a bug?
Or did I mess something up?

Comment: If I interpret things correctly, "a duplicate" is subsumed under "should be closed". If you raise one close-flag, you can't raise another one on the same question.

Comment: @DanielFischer I thought some of the close reasons are possibly only temporary (like unclear, incomplete), because they can be fixed by an edit of the asker. (That's why it then adds [on hold] to the title, right?), but a duplicate is a duplicate and nothing will change that, which makes this a more permanent close. That's why I was surprised about the behaviour and brought it up here. Your interpretation makes sense, too.

Comment: Closing things as duplicates seems preferable to closing for other reasons - so it's good to never intentionally close a duplicate for any other reason. Of course, as I assume happened here, the sequence of "closed, reopened, then later found to be & closed as a duplicate" strikes me as something which shouldn't happened often, so this is somewhat of an edge case.

Comment: @MiloBrandt I rather think the flag was still pending given the description.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The message in red says "you have already raised this **type** of flag". Unfortunately it does not explain what the types are... there are four of them for questions.

1. Spam and rude/abusive flags
2. Closeflag: "should be closed" or "duplicate"
3. Very low quality
4. Custom flag for mod attention

Generally, you can only raise a flag of each type once. (Custom flags are an exception. Another exception: if your close flag has expired without a decision, you can cast it again after a period of time.) And you cannot have two pending flags on the same post, regardless of the type.

(For completeness: you also can't cast VLQ while the question is in the close queue, or if it has a positive score.)

Comment: Custom flags can also be repeated.

Comment: @Asaf Are you sure? [This thread seems to disagree...](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/21734/10014) (I don't know, I've never tried.)

Comment: @Najib: That thread is about *adding* a second flag to a currently open flag. And yes, I am sure.

Comment: @Asaf I see, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 5):

Duplicate flags and other close flags are both the same *type* of flag. And you can only raise one flag of each *type*.

Since you'd already raised the Unclear flag, you were prevented from raising any further Close flags. You could still leave a comment guiding the asker to the original question, of course.

Comment: thanks for clarification, I was under the impression that each entry in the list is one type